# How to solve a symbolic non-linear vector equation? (Matlab or other)

Tags: math, equation, solver

I'm trying to find a solution to this symbolic non-linear vector equation:

```
P = a*(V0*t+P0) + b*(V1*t+P1) + (1-a-b)*(V2*t+P2) for a, b and t
```

where P, V0, V1, V2, P0, P1, P2 are known 3d vectors.

I attempted to do that in Matlab like this:

```
P = sym('P', [3,1])
P0 = sym('P0', [3,1])
P1 = sym('P1', [3,1])
P2 = sym('P2', [3,1])
V0 = sym('V0', [3,1])
V1 = sym('V1', [3,1])
V2 = sym('V2', [3,1])
syms a b t
F = a*(V0*t+P0) + b*(V1*t+P1) + (1-a-b)*(V2*t+P2) - P
solve(F,a,b,t)
```

I get

```
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
```

I'm starting to run out of ideas how to solve it, this isn't the first math package I tried.

The interesting bit is that this equation has a simple geometrical interpretation. If you imagine that points P0-P2 are vertices of a triangle, V0-V2 are roughly vertex normals and point P lies above the triangle, then the equation is satisfied for a triangle containing point P with it's three vertices on the three rays (V*t+P), sharing the same parameter t value. a, b and (1-a-b) become the barycentric coordinates of the point P.

So if the case is not degenerate, there should be only one well defined solution for t.

Comment: I tried solving the equation with Maxima as well. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

As symbolic equation, this one has 3 variables, so there is no way to have a single solution.

Imagine you pick any values for say b and t. Then in almost all cases you can solve for a, so you get many different solutions.

If you want to think geometrically, imagine that V0 and V1 point in the upper half-space regarding the (P0,P1,P2) triangle, but V2 point in the lower. Also V0,V1 are perpendicular to the plane of the triangle and V0 and V1 are unit vectors. 
Now if you have a plane pinned at the point P, which intersects the rays P0+t*V0 and P1+t*V1 at the same distance above the triangle, you can move the plane in such a way that it stays pinned at P and intersecting the two rays at the same distance. It's only a matter of having had picked V2 in such a way that the point of intersection with this plane moves at the same velocity, so it will correspond to the same t, thus giving you infinitely many solutions.

Another example would be if all V0-V2 were colinear with the triangle P0,P1,P2. Then you trivially get a solution for any t.

So you need more equations to solve this symbolically.

Comment: Since it's a 3 dimensional equation, it's actually 3 linearly independent equations - so in a not degenerate case there's exactly one solution.

The case you're describing is only possible if P is contained within the (P0,P1,P2) triangle (imagine what happens when t equals 0).

Of course any set of equations can become linearly dependant with specific data making the problem under-constrained. Like a ray-plane intersection: usually there's exactly one solution, unless the ray is parallel to the plane - then there's 0 or infinitely many solutions. Does that mean the symbolic form is unsolvable?

Comment: oh good point... I don't know what I was dreaming. But then you have the solution - just represent this as a system of 3 equations and solve it - any software for symbolic equation solving (Matlab, Mathematica, Maple, etc.) should be able to do it. I in fact don't know Matlab.